# relatedTo using product type?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a way to dynamically get all the related products based on the product type?

I seem to be getting all the products regardless of product type when I use:

`{% set products = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(category).order('postDate desc') %}`

(obviously since I don't have any categories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear but I think you're looking for:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.type('productTypeHandle').order('postDate desc') %}
```